# iPhoneSDK: Weird bug after pushing a detailviewcontroller while the keyboard is still open

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a very weird bug here, this is the scenario;

-I click on one of the textfields on my UITableView, uikeyboard appears,

-**Then without pressing done**, I click another textfield on screen(a disabled one),

-This disabled textfield pushes a detailview controller,

-I do my job on the detailview and **return back**,

-Surprize! the main UITableview is no more scrollable to bottom anymore! so I can not edit the bottom cells anymore!

This does not happen **IF** I press done after editing(so close the keyboard) and then click the detail view, now it works good.

I think it is something about resignfirstResponder is not called before I switch to another view, so I tried to send this msg to all the textfields in the tableview..but it got worse.

I tried also adding this line below just before I push the detailviewcontroller, but not worked, this is interssting cause this is what I call to resign the number pad normally, and it works when it is called from my custom "done" button to dismiss the nuber pad

```
[[self view] endEditing:YES];
```

And this is how I set the uikeyboards depend on the content in cellforRowAtIndex method

```
    if(somelogic){      
    cell.textField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;                
    [self resignFirstResponder];        
    [self becomeFirstResponder];        
}

else{       
    cell.textField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    [self resignFirstResponder];        
    [self becomeFirstResponder];        
}
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `[currentTextField resignFirstResponder]` before you push the detail view controller.

Set the *currentTextField* in the following method.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    currentTextField = textField;
    // Your code here 
}
```

Comment: i tried and not worked, cause also the currentTextField is not the one with the keyboard but the previous one is.

Comment: Did you set the currentTextField properly? See my updated answer

Comment: anyway I dont retain the currentTextField is that a problem?

Comment: No. You don't have to retain currentTextField as we are just keeping the reference of the current text field being edited

Comment: as I said not works..also makes it crash when I hang around a little on that page and pressing around

Answer (score 0):

Occam's razor. 
**Don't let them not click the done button**.

Put a transparent UIButton accross the entire screen. Show it when you call `[textField becomeFirstResponder]`. You can either prevent people from touching the screen and switching textFields, or call `[textField resignFirstResponder]` when it is tapped.

Comment: In your code, the textFields should resignFirstResponder, not the viewController.

Comment: I saw this hack in S.O and works well but if I make them [cell.textfield resignFirstResponder] as u suggest code doesnot work anymore and keyboards fly around juts without editing any textfield